# Will anyone figure out who I am if I am downloading torrent while logged in facebook in my browser?

Tags: vpn, facebook, isp, udp, torrent

I have protonvpn. I am downloading torrents. I don't want anyone to know that I am downloading torrents. I am also logged in to Facebook in my browser. So Facebook knows my VPN IP.

And my ISP knows the IP from which I am downloading stuff using UDP.

Will someone be able to figure out who I am from these sources?

Comment: Who is "anyone"?

Comment: If someone had access to Facebook's logs, could correlate the IP to your account, had the ISP logs, and your torrent traffic, then someone could piece together all that data to see that someone from your household was downloading torrents. With enough access to enough data, all activity can be traced. But it is not likely that "anyone" could get all that data.

Comment: Technically the VPN provider could know it too.

Comment: Why does your ISP know where you are downloading torrents, if you are using a VPN? Aren't you using the VPN for DNS traffic as well?